# Group Extension Example

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-extensions

I am trying to find two distinct group extension of $Z_2$ by $Z_3$. One "natural" extension that I found was $(Z_3,Z_2)$. That is $0 \rightarrow Z_3\rightarrow (Z_3,Z_2)\rightarrow Z_2\rightarrow 0$. However, I am having difficulty in finding another one. Any hints?

Comment: Is $(\Bbb{Z}_3, \Bbb{Z}_2) = \Bbb{Z}_3 \times \Bbb{Z}_2$, the cartesian product?

Comment: Do you know about semidirect products?

Comment: @SammyBlack: Yes it is cartesian product. Yes, I am familliar with semidirect products

Answer (score 1):

There are two (split) extensions, depending on which homomorphism you choose
$$
\Bbb{Z}_2 \to \operatorname{Aut} \Bbb{Z}_3 \cong C_2.
$$
(I prefer the cyclic group notation $C_2$ for automorphisms that are written multiplicatively, although, of course, $C_2 \cong \Bbb{Z}_2$ as abstract groups.)

If you choose the trivial homomorphism, then you get the direct product.  Whereas, if you choose the isomorphism, then you get the semidirect product that is isomorphic to $D_3 \cong S_3$, the symmetries of an equilateral triangle.  (The first map embeds $\Bbb{Z}_3$ as the subgroup $A_3$ of rotations and the second projects onto the sign of the permutation.)

Comment: Will these two extensions be non isomorphic. It seems like they won't be.

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}_3 \times \Bbb{Z}_2 \cong \Bbb{Z}_6$ is abelian, while $\Bbb{Z}_3 \rtimes \Bbb{Z}_2 \cong S_3$ is not.

Comment: There are not so many groups of order six anyway